# The energy method for $u_{tt}-du_t-u_{xx}=0, (0,1)\times(0,T) $

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, linear-pde

It is a problem in Evan's PDE. I want to prove the smooth solution of the following PDE is zero:
$$u_{tt}-du_t-u_{xx}=0, (0,1)\times(0,T) $$$u|_{x=0}=u|_{x=1}=u|_{t=0}=u_t|_{t=0}=0$.

---

The hint is to use the energy $\frac{1}{2}(||\partial_tu||_{L^2[0,1]}+||\partial_xu||_{L^2[0,1]})$, but when I differentiate the energy, I can only get the first and third term of PDE

Comment: I suppose that it comes from applying the energy method in problem 10 of chapter 7 (p. 448 in 2nd ed., 2010). Note the $+$ sign in $+d u_t$ (*telegraph equation*). It would be better to provide exact citation of the book, and attempts.

Comment: The energy is, I think, $\frac{1}{2}(||\partial_tu||_{L^2[0,1]}^2+||\partial_xu||_{L^2[0,1]}^2)$

Answer (score 4):

Let us assume that the solution is sufficiently smooth and $d<0$. The time-derivative of the energy
$E(t) = \frac{1}{2}\left( \|u_t\|_{L^2[0,1]}^2 + \|u_x\|_{L^2[0,1]}^2\right)$ writes
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}E(t) &= \int_0^1 \left( u_{tt}\, u_{t} + u_{xt}\, u_{x} \right) \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \left( u_{tt}\, u_{t} + u_{tx}\, u_{x} \right) \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 u_{tt}\, u_{t}\, \text{d}x + \left[ u_{t}\, u_{x} \right]_0^1 - \int_0^1 u_{t}\, u_{xx}\, \text{d}x \\
&= \int_0^1 \left(u_{tt} - u_{xx}\right) u_{t}\, \text{d}x \\
&= d\int_0^1 (u_{t})^2\, \text{d}x \\
&\leq 0 \, .
\end{aligned}
$$
To show that the energy is decreasing, we have used successively the equality of mixed derivatives, integration by parts, the fact that $u$ is constant-in-time at the boundaries $x=0$ and $x=1$ of the domain, and the PDE itself. Since at $t=0$, the energy is $E(0) = 0$ and the energy is always positive, we have shown that the energy is equal to zero for all $t$, which means that $u$ is constant in time and space. Now, since it equals zero at the boundaries of the domain, it is necessary that $u$ is identically zero.

Comment: Nice job, ***endorsed***.  I noticed you use  $\frac{1}{2}(||\partial_tu||_{L^2[0,1]}^2+||\partial_xu||_{L^2[0,1]}^2)$ for the energy; see my comment on the question itself.

Comment: My pleasure, sir!

Comment: @EditPiAf how do we solve this problem when d is non negative?

Comment: @User124356 If $d> 0$ the above problem for $u_{tt} - u_{xx} = du_t$ is not well-posed. (+ See the comments to OP)

Comment: @EditPiAf Why is the problem ill-posed when $d>0$ (or when $d<0$ in Evan's original formulation)?

Comment: @Aberkeltz In physics, we don't like it when the energy increases. Neither in mathematics, since we can't use the decreasing energy argument anymore to prove that $u$ is identically zero

Answer (score 1):

When $d>0$ the uniqueness still follows. For the energy $E(t):=\frac12( \|u_t\|_{L^2}^2+\|u_x\|_{L^2}^2)$, we get $$E'(t)= d\int_0^1(u_t)^2~dx\leq d\left(\int_0^1(u_t)^2+(u_x)^2~dx\right)=2d E(t).$$
Then multiplying $e^{-2dt}$ on both sides, we find $$\frac{d}{dt}\left(e^{-2dt}E(t)\right)\leq 0.$$ That means $e^{-2dt}E(t)$ is decreasing in time, but $E(0)=0$ forces $e^{-2dt}E(t)=0$ for $0<t<T$.