# Telegraph equation - energy method

Tags: partial-differential-equations

i'm struggling to prove solution uniqueness with this one.
thanks for the assistance.

$$u_{tt}+u_{t}=u_{xx} $$
$$u_x(0,t)=u_x(\pi,t)=0 $$
$$u(x,0)=1$$
$$u_t(x,0)=\cos^2(x)$$

Prove the uniqueness of the solution

well, i defines two solutions, $$w(x,t)=u(x,t)-v(x,t) $$ in aim to show $$w(x,t)=0 $$ and therefore $$ u(x,t)=v(x,t)$$

i multiplied each side of the equation with $w$ and integrated it, to get:
$$\int_0^\pi  w(w_{tt}+w_{t}) dx=\int_0^\pi  ww_{xx} dx$$
$$\int_0^\pi  ww_{tt}+\int_0^\pi ww_{t} dx=\int_0^\pi  ww_{xx} dx$$
where,
$$ww_{t}=\frac{d}{dt}\big[\frac{1}{2}w^2\big] \rightarrow \frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi w^2 dx $$
by integration by part i got the follows:
$$E'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi w^2 dx = \int_0^\pi w_t^2-w_x^2 dx$$

am i in the right way?
asking your as guidance

Comment: See also this strongly related [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2616317/418542)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is better to write down an explicit energy first and do the calculations with that one. Try this definition of an energy for your $w$:
$$E(w(\cdot,t)):=\int_0^\pi (w_x)^2 + (w_t)^2\, dx.$$
This $E$ is always nonnegative. Now show $\frac{d}{dt}E(w(\cdot,t))\leq 0$ and $E(w(\cdot,0))=0$ (these will need the equation, the initial and boundary data and partial integration). I leave these steps for you to complete yourself.

On another note: It seems to me, you used partial integration to infer the following:
$$\int_0^\pi w w_{tt}\, dx = - \int_0^\pi (w_t)^2\, dx.$$
Since the integration is with respect to $x$ and the derivative with respect to $t$, this step is not correct.